# Install xdebug for lamp

Tags: php, ubuntu, makefile, xdebug

I have big troubles installing xdebug and get it working with my lamp installation. I'm on an ubuntu system and i installed xdebug via `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`.

I also have a standalone php binary, for which xdebug automatically installed fine. I located the xdebug.so and added the `zend_extension=path/to/xdebug.so` in my `lamp/etc/php.ini`. However i got an error

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

which probably means that my lamp runs in differnt bit mode than my standalone php.

However i went to xdebug.com and downloaded the source. Followed the steps mentioned in the manual installation:

```
/opt/lamp/bin/phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
make
```

(The first time phpize complained about missing autoconf so i also to install autoconf `sudo apt-get install autoconf`).

Then again when running `make` i ran into the follwing error

```
fatal error: php.h: file or directory not found
```

Also phpize had some warnings and also didn't print any API numbers which is probably related.

```
grep: [path]/php.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
grep: [path]/Zend/zend_modules.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
grep: [path]/Zend/zend_extensions.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:  
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
configure.in:3: warning: prefer named diversions
```

Anyway, so xdebug didn't work with lamp out of the box and i couldn't compile it from the sources either.

I hope somebody has suggestions what i could try next.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/ and install the `devel` version of xampp.

Without the development version you won't be able to compile any packages simply because the regular version does not contain the necessary sources.

Comment: Okay i will try that on the weekend. Do you know if it replaces the old lamp installation and does it affect my data such as database contents?

Comment: I don't think it should override your DB but make a copy just in case. I have almost no experience with XAMPP so I cannot promise you anything.